# How to optimize the code for this situation？

Tags: python, django, django-models

I defined several Django models and need to process the field value like the following, the codes are so redundant

```
version = 'xxxx'

version_objs  = AP_Release_Version.objects.filter(ap_version__icontains=version)
for version_obj in version_objs:
    version_value = version_obj.ap_version
    ......

version_objs  = CP_Release_Version.objects.filter(cp_version__icontains=version)
for version_obj in version_objs:
    version_value = version_obj.cp_version
    ......

version_objs = GPS_Release_Version.objects.filter(gps_version__icontains=version)
for version_obj in version_objs:
    version_value = version_obj.gps_version
    ......
```

---

Is there any way to optimize the code like define the mapping info? thanks

```
map_info = {
    'ap_version'  : 'AP_Release_Version',
    'cp_version'  : 'CP_Release_Version',
    'gps_version' : 'GPS_Release_Version',
}
```

Then I can do like this:

```
for key in map_info:
    version_objs  = map_info['key'].objects.filter(key__icontains=version)
    for version_obj in version_objs:
        version_value = version_obj.key
```

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like you have three variables: the object, the icontains, and the attribute. So create a list of tuples:

```
import collections
VersionInfo = collections.namedtuple('VersionInfo', 'obj icontains attrname')

Vinfos = [
    VersionInfo(AP_Release_Version, 'ap_version__icontains', 'ap_version'),
    VersionInfo(CP_Release_Version, 'cp_version__icontains', 'cp_version'),
    VersionInfo(GPS_Release_Version, 'gps_version__icontains', 'gps_version'),
]

for vinfo in Vinfos:
    kwargs = {vinfo.icontains : version }
    version_objs = vinfo.obj.objects.filter(**kwargs)

    for version_obj in version_objs:
        version_value = getattr(version_obj, vinfo.attrname)
        ...
```

Comment: collections seems a powerful module , I'm a newcomer to python and will learn it later , many thanks for your kindly help :)

Comment: Austin Hastings hi , I learned and found it's flexible and powerful to get the objs and attrname_value by this way , thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

have an idea, using kwargs:

```
map_info = {
    'ap_version'  : AP_Release_Version,
    'cp_version'  : CP_Release_Version,
    'gps_version' : GPS_Release_Version,
}

for k, v in map_info.items():
    version_objs = v.objects.filter(**{'%s_icontains' %k : version})
    for version_obj in version_objs:
        version_value = version_obj.key
```

Comment: 朋友有邮件联系方式么？ Django 新手，不懂的还望多多指教啊 ^^

Comment: I actually know little about Django. This is my email: yuanwang.bupt  # gmail

Comment: OK , nice to meet you ~~ ^0^